# Applescript code doesn't not work on big batch of files

Tags: applescript

I write a code that works on a folder with 750 files, but when I use it on a folder with 5000 files, it doesn't work, the code is:

```
set filenamelist to choose file with prompt "Please select files name list to 

process:" of type {"csv"}
set checkfolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the source folder") as text
set destinationfolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose your destination folder for the copied files.") as alias
set listOfbarcods to {}
set listtttt to paragraphs of (read filenamelist as «class utf8»)
repeat with nextLine in listtttt
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
        set nextLine1 to text 2 thru -2 of nextLine
        copy nextLine1 & ".pdf" as text to the end of listOfbarcods
    end if
end repeat

set noitem to "0"
with timeout of 3600 seconds
    repeat with theItem in listOfbarcods
        try
            do shell script "mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of checkfolder & quoted form of theItem & space & quoted form of POSIX path of destinationfolder
        end try
        delay 0.1
        set noitem to (noitem + 1)
    end repeat
end timeout
display dialog noitem & " Files Copied" as text
```

Comment: What *doesn't work*? Unrelated but the `timeout` block is pointless because no Apple Events are sent inside the block. And declare `noitem` as integer (`set noitem to 0`), a string makes no sense. And you can write the move line more efficient: Before the loop insert `set checkFolderPOSIX to POSIX path of checkfolder` and replace the beginning of the move line with `do shell script "mv " & quoted form of (checkFolderPOSIX & theItem) & space &...`

Comment: Also, remove the try/end try lines so you can see what happens (and what fails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code contains a **whole chain of errors**. The fact that it worked at all is due to the AppleScript language, which is able to fix many errors at runtime. The biggest problem I see is that instead of checking to see if the file has moved completely, you are hard-coding the amount of time you give to shell command to move file (**delay 0.1**). I tried to fix the code. Some coercions and parentheses are optional, but it's better to make it clearer for you how everything works.

```
set filenamelist to choose file with prompt "Please select files name list to 

process:" of type {"csv"}
set listtttt to paragraphs of (read filenamelist as «class utf8»)
set checkfolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the source folder")
set destinationfolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose your destination folder for the copied files.")

set listOfbarcods to {}
repeat with nextLine in listtttt
    if length of nextLine is greater than 1 then -- EDITED
        set nextLine1 to text 2 thru -2 of nextLine
        copy ((contents of nextLine1) & ".pdf") to the end of listOfbarcods -- EDITED
    end if
end repeat

set noitem to 0 -- EDITED
set destinationQuotedPath to quoted form of POSIX path of destinationfolder -- ADDED
repeat with theItem in listOfbarcods
    -- append the item to the path, then quote full path at once
    set itemQuotedPath to quoted form of ((POSIX path of checkfolder) & (contents of theItem)) -- ADDED
    do shell script "mv " & itemQuotedPath & space & destinationQuotedPath -- EDITED
    repeat 30 times -- ADDED the loop (maximum - about 3 seconds)
        delay 0.1
        try -- check if the item is moved completly
            alias ((checkfolder as text) & (contents of theItem))
            set noitem to noitem + 1 -- EDITED
            exit repeat
        end try
    end repeat
end repeat

display dialog (noitem as text) & " Files Copied" -- EDITED
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert, I appreciate this, I'm new to AppleScript., your code clarify lots of things for me.